# Pipe a stream to nowhere

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a stream of data and I need to write it to nowhere, but without immediately stopping it. The code below writes to a file, so it keeps the connection alive for as long as the stream is going.

```
 request
.get(href)
.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode)
    console.log(response.headers['content-type'])
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("name.mp3"))
```

Is it possible to pipe that stream to nowhere, while still keeping the connection like `fs.createWritableStream` ?

I tried using dev-null (npm package), but it seems to just kill the connection immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a strange problem, but maybe you can use `/dev/null`, or the Windows equivalent explained in the post below?

[How can I write to the NUL device under Windows from node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053977/how-can-i-write-to-the-nul-device-under-windows-from-node-js)

I do see that you tried something similar with the `dev-null` package, but maybe try it without the package and see if that works.

Comment: .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("\\\\.\\NUL")) helped to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No package required, on linux (see almarc's comment on Hein's answer for Windows):

```
request
.get(href)
.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode)
    console.log(response.headers['content-type'])
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("/dev/null")).
```